# Can't get a .post with 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' to work Axios React Native

Tags: react-native, post, file-upload, axios, content-type

i'm trying to upload **FormData** which include **text ,image,pdf etc**

I am using **axios**.

> **Axios Call**

```
const sellerRegister = params => {
  console.log(params);
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(servicePending());
    return axios
      .post(`${BaseUrl}/seller/register`, params, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${params._boundary}`
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        return dispatch(sellerRegisterSuccess(res));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return dispatch(serviceError(err.message));
      });
  };
};
```

> **Params in FormData**

[image: include **text,pdf,image**]

> **ServiceError**

[image]

**Provide solutions of this error. and also guide me am i doing this in right way or not ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of Axios, you make an HTTP request with 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' in the header as follows:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('action', 'ADD');
formData.append('param', 0);
formData.append('secondParam', 0);
formData.append('file', new Blob(['test payload'], { type: 'text/csv' }));
axios({
  url: 'http://your_host/api/auth_user',
  method: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
```

use url instead of uri.

or
You can do simply:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data; 
boundary=someArbitraryUniqueString';
```

Comment: in new Blob(['test payload']).      what does 'test payload' means. ?

Comment: name of file ,uri of file something ?

Comment: thanks for help.  actually i was having another issue .   my dubugger was on that's app wasn't processing request correctly

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq How to set the boundary correctly i.e, what should be its value?